# Saving multiple Dataframe in separate tabs/sheets of the workbook

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

How can I save DataFrames in different tab/sheets of the same Excel spreadsheet?

In my spreadsheet, there are different sheets. I've performed some operation on the Dataframe from each sheet & now want to save each one in a separate tab/sheet.

I tried with `pd.ExcelWriter(file_name_with_path) as writer` but it overwrites the earlier sheets and saving the last one in the workbook.

```
def redact_excel(excel_name):
    excel_basename = os.path.basename(excel_name)

    workbook = pd.read_excel(excel_name, engine="openpyxl", sheet_name=None)

    for sheet_name, dataframe in workbook.items():
    
       save_path = './redacted_excels/'
       file_name_with_path = os.path.join(save_path, excel_basename)
       with pd.ExcelWriter(file_name_with_path) as writer:
           print(sheet_name)
           dataframe.to_excel(writer, index=False, sheet_name=sheet_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use the `startrow` parameter in `pandas`

Try this -

```
dataframe.to_excel(writer, startrow=len(dataframe)+1, index=False, header=None)
```